# Using Cursor to retrieve SQLite db

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, google-maps

I don't think I've been doing this right. A buddy told me to use the cursor.getColumnIndex() to retrieve the values of the items in that table column. Looks to me like it just returns an int value of the position of the column in the table which is why when I execute the code below I get either a 2.0 or 3.0 for my lat and long values as they are the second and third column in the table.

What is the correct way to have this method return the items in the lat long columns instead of their position in the table?

Here is what I was using with the getColumnIndex() :

```
public List<LatLng> getAllPositions() {
     List<LatLng> positionList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
      SQLiteDatabase database;
      ResumeMySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

      dbHelper = new ResumeMySQLiteHelper(this);
     database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

     String[] allColumns = { ResumeMySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
              ResumeMySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT, ResumeMySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LAT, ResumeMySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LONG };

     Cursor cursor = database.query(ResumeMySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,
         allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

     cursor.moveToFirst();
     while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { 


         double latitude = cursor.getColumnIndex("lat");
         double longitude = cursor.getColumnIndex("long");
         String testString = Double.toString(latitude);
         String testLong = Double.toString(longitude);
         Log.w("myApp", testString + " " + testLong);

         //currently prints myApp 2.0 3.0 for every row in table

         LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
         positionList.add(newLatLng);
         cursor.moveToNext();
     }
     // make sure to close the cursor
     cursor.close();
     return positionList;
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
double latitude = cursor.getColumnIndex("lat");
```

should be:

```
double latitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
```

and the same for double longitude

Comment: yep you got that one :D

Comment: I just read the question some minutes before you did. Or you would have answered the same. ;)

Comment: @ArtooDetoo while reading, i was like aahh this is the problem. and bammm one answer. read yours. was like its all over ;)

Comment: It happens to me as well... it's just a matter of seconds, sometimes. ;) Next time you'll be faster than me!

Answer (score 1):

`int cloumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("lat");`
 provides you index of the column that holds "lat" value
after finding the index of that column you need to find value.

```
cursor.getDouble(columnIndex);
```